# What is alternate for [RoutePrefix("api/{controller})] in .net core 3.1?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I am migrating Asp.net(.net framework) project Asp.net core(.net core 3.1 framework).
I am unable to find the alternate to

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/{controller})]
```

in .net core 3.1?

Any idea, how we can achieve this?

Comment: you can use [Route("api/{controller})]  as well

Comment: Just use the `Route` attribute.

Comment: How it work if we have [Route("GetData")] at method level?

Comment: You then would need the `[HttpGet]` attribute on that method... and your route would be something like: `[Route("~/api/People/GetData")]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using for example:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put `[Route("api/[controller]")]` at the controller level, you can use `[Route("Action")]` on the method, and the route will be `site.com/api/controller/Action`.

Something to note is that if you use `Route("/Action")]` (with a slash), it will overwrite the controller-level route and just give you the action (`site.com/Action`)